# How to access Constraint Data Programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I would like to access **firstAttribute constraint property** programatically. so that i can able to find if a constraint is height constraint,width constraint,topMargin constraint etc...
when i try,

```
print(constraint.firstAttribute)
```

i get the general result as

> "NSLayoutAttribute"

but what i want more specific result to treat the constraints differently based on it ***attribute(height,width,topMargin etc..)*** type.

Comment: Classic XY problem here. You are asking how to do what you think will solve the problem you have. You should be asking how to solve the problem. The problem is not that you want to find the constraint from a view. The problem is that you want to update the constraint and need access to it in order to update it.

Comment: There was a question - sorry, can't find it now - that the answer detailed how to search through constraints and *list out* what they were. But I really don't think this is the correct way to deal with this. (In fact, I don't think you'll be able to change what you find this way.) (1) What *specifically are you trying to change? (2) Why aren't you trying the usual route - either adding the constraint as an `@IBOutlet` or declaring the constraint in your code? There's a *major* difference between "finding" a constraint and "changing" it.

Comment: Reading through your comments on the answer, one must suggest that you look into refactoring your "hundreds" of constraints. It extremely poor design, and will be a headache to maintain. (And yes, I pity the person picking up where you left off.) Consider `UIStackView`, `UICollectionView`, even just simplifying the layout you have. Nobody should have to programmatically change that may constraints in their code. If you take the time to learn proper layout of constraints *today*, it'll pay off for you in the future.

Comment: Peace. I down-voted your question because it was very vague. And yes, based on (a) the question, (b) your comments, and (c) what you *finally* state is your *real* reason for "hundreds" of constraints - I'll stand by that down-vote. This type of question - both vague and unable to be duplicated - doesn't belong on SO. As for me, I'm freely giving of my time and 35 years experience (the last 5 in iOS and Swift) with no expectations of getting anything in return. My criticisms were meant to help. Show me an app with "hundreds" of constraints and I'll show you an app that can be refactored.

Comment: hello all, i improved my question which suits to the answer i selected. so i hope that all of you will delete the comments as it no longer related to the question. it also helps other viewers so please consider my request. i deleted my comments.

Comment: @dfd it could be nice if you motivated me to write better question instead of insulting that it shouldn't be on SO. we all start as a beginner, dont forgot that.

Comment: I don't need to! You should already know, provided you've read what makes a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Again, peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property on the constraint that you're looking for is `firstAttribute` (or `secondAttribute`). However, there's really no reason you should need to "guess" which constraint you're looking at - just store the constraints as properties and name them accordingly.

EDIT: to tell which type of attribute you have, switch over it:

```
switch myConstraint.firstAttribute {
    case .height:
    // height constraint
    case .leading:
    // leading constraint
    case .topMargin:
    // top margin constraint
    // etc
}
```

Comment: it (constraint.firstAttribute) prints "NSLayoutAttribute". which is not helping :(

Comment: same result for secondAtribute too.

Comment: actually i have a reason. i am dealing with outlet collection of constraints. so there is no way to name the constraint properly.

Comment: See my edit. You could `print` inside each `case` statement, but I assumed printing was just a placeholder and you wanted to actually do something based on the type of attribute.

Comment: And why not just wire a single constraint at a time via IBOutlet?

Comment: Glad it's what you're looking for. But as anyone who's worked on large scale apps can tell you, there is no scenario where you should need to do this. In even the most complex screen layouts iOS can handle, there is no reason you should have to manipulate more than a handful of constraints. Those handful of constraints should be able to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to store the constraint as a property. You can do this with an outlet from a storyboard or nib (just like a button or label) or in code.

That way, you don’t have to dive into the view to try and find the constraint. You just access it like...

```
buttonHeightConstraint.constant = 50
```

Etc...

Comment: i am dealing with 100s of constraints . i dont want to create outlet for each and every constraint that will make it extremely hard. i added all the constraint in a outlet collection so now i just need to find out what the constraint property is . i.e if its leading or trailing or if its horizontal or vertical constraint. so that i can apply math using condtional statements.

Comment: @SatishSa how many constraints are you updating? Are you updating hundreds of them? Or just one?

Comment: @SatishSa also, don't state something like it's obvious if you have literally never mentioned it before. Where in your question did you mention "100s of constraints" and also... if you are creating outlet for all of them then I think you're doing something wrong. How many of the constraints do you actually need to update/access?

Comment: i am trying some sort of percentage based layout. so what i did was, i first added all constraints into single outlet collection then i have now two formula lets XA,XB. i need to apply XA formula only to constraints which is horizontal or leading,trailing etc.. and i need to apply XB forumla to constraints which is vertical. so that i can process each constraint using for loop. hope its understandable.

Comment: @SatishSa tbh it's not very clear. I still think there are much easier ways to approach this. Can you show what you mean via a screenshot or image in your question. I think you are possibly approaching this problem in entirely the wrong way.

Comment: ill make it simple but please dont ask why i need to do that. the reason is am trying something different.

Comment: lets assume i created a button with two constraint proeprties height and width. now i dragged in both of those constraints from storyboard to swift file and created a outlet collection group. now with the help of for loop i can process each constraint seperately in a group. now i need to find if the constraint is a width constraint or height constraint so that i can apply different formulas for them.

Comment: @SatishSa yes, I get that. What I don't understand is what your end game is. Is it that you want this hypothetical button to be resizable based on some value? Is your view resizable? Rather than creating outlets for 100s of constraints it would seem like a better approach to make these constraints relative to a shared superview. So that all you need to do is resize the superview and all the 100s of constraints will update themselves automatically. You don't need to iterate anything then.

Comment: @SatishSa I just feel like what you're doing is solvable in a much easier way but without know what you're trying to do I don't know if I can offer any more help.

Comment: thank you for helping me. you helped me to write better so others can understand. thanks again i found out the solution you can check it.

Comment: @SatishSa no problem at all :) glad I was able to help some how :)

Answer (score 0):

For me **firstAttribute** didn't work at all, and also, it's not compatible with versions prior to iOS 9.0

So I finally solved by assigning an identifier to the NSLayoutConstraint object. Then, you can iterate though the constraints of your view and compare the identifier to retrieve the desired constraint.

```
yourConstraint.identifier = "yourString"
```

So:

```
for tmpConst in self.view.constraints {
        if tmpConst.identifier == "yourString" {
            return tmpConst
        }
}
```

Will return your constraint.